# Compile error while yielding a sequence through mutable variable

Tags: f#

I am writing a function that takes a multi-line string through a `StringReader` and returns each line as an item of a `seq`

```
let symbolSeq = seq {

    let mutable line = reader.ReadLine()

    while !line <> null  do
        yield line
        line <- reader.ReadLine()
}
```

I am getting a

> This expression was expected to have type 'a ref but here has type string
>
> on while !--->line<--- <> null do

When I get rid of the `!` in front of `line` I get a

> The mutable variable 'line' is used in an invalid way. Mutable variables cannot be captured by closures. Consider eliminating this use of mutation or using a heap-allocated mutable reference cell via 'ref' and '!'.

Why ?

Answer (score 3):

Because a seq-expression implicitly creates closures, and you can't close over mutable variables in F#.

Comment: @Reviewers! Dammit, read the comment to the edit before just rejecting. fahadash was trying to add a part to thr's answer, which thr himself wrote to fahadash in IRC.

Comment: @BjarkeFreund-Hansen and I removed it because it's not relevant to the question which is about why it's giving him an error about closing over mutable values. It has nothing to do with string reader, etc. per say.,

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the line value in a ref cell as mutable values can't be closed over.

```
let symbolSeq = seq {
let line = ref (reader.ReadLine())
while !line <> null do
    yield !line
    line := reader.ReadLine()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using a ref cell is to use recursion and yield!:

```
let symbolSeq =
    let rec iterate (reader : System.IO.StringReader) =
        seq
            {
                match reader.ReadLine() with
                    | null -> ()
                    | x ->
                        yield x
                        yield! iterate reader
            }

    iterate reader
```